# Pattern to ignore 'history numlines' in HISTIGNORE, bash

Tags: bash, command-history

What would be the correct pattern for ignoring commands such as:

```
history 10
history 104
history .. #whatever may be the number here
```

I tried:

```
HISTIGNORE='history\s+\d*'
```

but that doesn't work.

Comment: That uses shell patterns not regular expressions. `HISTIGNORE='history [0-9]*'` might work.

Comment: How about optional number of spaces? Is that possible, beacause right now `history   20` got recorded?

Comment: Try 'history \*[0-9]*'

Comment: Now `history` only by itself is being remembered. :) Why is that, when spaces and digits are 0 or more?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The value of `HISTIGNORE` is a list of shell patterns. Not a list of regular expressions. As such the regular expressions will not work.

This pattern `'history *[0-9]*'` should do what is needed here.

Edit: Pulling in added information from the comments.

To also ignore `history` by itself the simplest solution is to just add `history` to the value of `HISTIGNORE`.

But, when `extglob` is enabled (and assuming `HISTIGNORE` honors it) this pattern should cover that as well:

```
'history?( *[0-9]*)'
```

Comment: Now history only, without any numlines param by itself is being remembered. Why is that, when spaces and digits are `0 or more`?

Comment: That is a good question. I'm not sure. If you turn on extglob (and if HISTIGNORE honors that) you can use `'history?( \*[0-9]*)` to match `history` too I think. But that's not exactly a satisfactory answer.

Comment: Are there any possibly bad implications involved, if `extglob` set?

Comment: I doubt it. I believe it just enabled previously erroring pattern strings. So it shouldn't affect anything that worked before and just allow things that didn't work before (well, it does change when history expansion for `!` is triggered a little bit by disabling `!(` as a context for history expansion). But you could just add `history` to `HISTIGNORE` also.

Comment: Well I use that a lot, things like `ls -l !cp:^`, thanks for pointing that out!

Comment: It won't break that. It only stops the `!` in a `!(` pair from being considered for expansion I believe. The man page talks about it briefly. "Several characters inhibit history expansion if found immediately following the history expansion character, even if it is unquoted: space, tab, newline, carriage return, and =.  If the extglob shell option is enabled, ( will also inhibit expansion."

Comment: That being said history expansion is a weird weird beast and if I didn't also routinely use things like `!!` and `!$` I would turn it off entirely.

Comment: Why did you escaped that `*` in `history?( \*[0-9]*)`, and not the other one after `[0-9]`?

Comment: Bah, that shouldn't be visible. I was trying to prevent SO from doing *this* to the range but clearly it doesn't do that in `*code*`. The correct pattern should be `'history?( *[0-9]*)'`.

Comment: Ok, I saw right now that my `shopt extglob` was `on` anyway, so not having any problems till now, I guess I can accept your answer on `history?( *[0-9]*)`. Please add that to your answer as an option, so I can mark it solved.

Answer (score 1):

To have multiple patterns you can separate them with a :

Like this:

```
HISTIGNORE="&:exit:pwd:rm *:history *:[ \t]*"
```

Comment: `[ \t]*` is not needed - we can use `HISTCONTROL=ignorespace`